# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters throws an exception when trying to use System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, swagger, swashbuckle, system.text.json

I've an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project on which I want to generate the API documentation along with queryable examples using Swagger.

I want to use the new `System.Text.Json` namespace instead of the good old `Newtonsoft.Json` one

As stated in the [Swagger documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft)

> If you're using System.Text.Json (STJ), then the setup described above will be sufficient, and STJ options/attributes will be automatically honored by the Swagger generator
>
> If you're using Newtonsoft, then you'll need to install a separate package and explicitly opt-in to ensure that Newtonsoft settings/attributes are automatically honored by the Swagger generator

I did **NOT** install the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` package and I did **NOT** call `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()`.

My controller's method looks like this (I want to convert Enums to string values instead of integers)

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Just a test Method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fooParams">My Params</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("Foo")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(FooResult))]
[SwaggerRequestExample(requestType: typeof(FooQuery), examplesProviderType: typeof(FooRequestExampleProvider), jsonConverter: typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(statusCode: 200, examplesProviderType: typeof(FooResponseExampleProvider), jsonConverter: typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public FooResult Foo([FromQuery]FooQuery fooParams)
{
    return _processor.Execute<FooQuery, FooResult>(fooParams);
}
```

However when I execute this method (called in my `Startup.cs`)

```cs
public static IApplicationBuilder UseVersionedSwagger(this IApplicationBuilder app, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
    });

    return app;
}
```

I get an exception saying

> System.InvalidCastException
>
> HResult=0x80004002
>
> Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter'.
>     Source=Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters

Here is the packages I reference in my `.csproj`

```xml
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.6.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="4.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server" Version="3.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Rebus.RabbitMq" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="4.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc5" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="5.0.0-rc9" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc5" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0-rc5" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi" Version="5.0.0-rc5" />
```

If I change my controller's method to use `Newtonsoft.Json` it works well, no exception

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Just a test Method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fooParams">My Params</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("Foo")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(FooResult))]
[SwaggerRequestExample(requestType: typeof(FooQuery), examplesProviderType: typeof(FooRequestExampleProvider), jsonConverter: typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
[[SwaggerResponseExample(statusCode: 200, examplesProviderType: typeof(FooResponseExampleProvider), jsonConverter: typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
public FooResult Foo([FromQuery]FooQuery fooParams)
{
    return _processor.Execute<FooQuery, FooResult>(fooParams);
}
```

I even tried to explicitly specify this in my `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
```

But still I'm not able to use `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter`, only `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter` works.

Here is my `FooQuery` class which contains a `FooEnum` property that I want to convert to string values in Swagger

```cs
public class FooQuery
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public FooEnum MyFooParam { get; set; }
}
```

So is my code incorrect somewhere? Did I miss something?

Or is it a problem with the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` package? Is the version `5.0.0-rc9` of this package buggy and not yet compatible with `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter`?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I'd post an issue on their GitHub.

Comment: Ok I'll do that then, I was hesitating

Comment: [Github issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/1356)

Comment: Your GitHub issue is logged in the wrong GitHub project.